# Getting New location from a Moveable marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, popup

I've created a page that has a static map on, complete with marker.

I have put a link underneath that then does a POPUP page with a larger map - same marker, but draggable.

What I am struggling with is;

a) Getting the new coordinates after a drag of the moveable marker. I have the following Eventlistener code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

   updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended'); 

   geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());   
document.write("I'm HERE");
});
```

..and am getting the 'I'm HERE' - but how do I get the new coordinates?

and

b) Once I have these values - how do I pass them back to the page that called the POPUP.

(My JS skills are limited, most of the site is in php and HTML.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Phil

Comment: We need more context.  marker.getPosition() should return the current coordinates of the marker.  So... marker.getPosition().lat() should give you the current latitude and marker.getPosition().lng() should give you the current longitude.  What does geocodePosition() do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newPosition = marker.getPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
marker.getPosition()
```

should return the current coordinates of the marker. So...

```
marker.getPosition().lat()
```

should give you the current latitude and

```
marker.getPosition().lng()
```

should give you the current longitude. What does geocodePosition() do?   Need more context to answer your second question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - and yes I guess that first part was something I should have been able to lookup. The geoCode function was just part of the sample code I found - having now looked at it I don't think its needed. For what its worth, this is what it did:

function geocodePosition(pos) { 
    geocoder.geocode({ 
    latLng: pos 
    }, function(responses) { 
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) { 
     updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address); 
     } else { 
     updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.'); 
     } 
    });

Comment: ignore end of above....
The 2nd part of the question is a JS query really. I have a link on the main page, under a static map, as below;

<a href='adjustmap.php?lat=$retLat&long=$retLong' onClick='return popup(this, \"adjustmap\")'>Click Here to Fine Tune Location</a> 

The onclick create a popup window with a bigger map in it with the draggable marker in. I now have the new coordinates in that popup - how do I get them back to the main form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the confused comments - was trying to paste code and was running out of characters.

Basically was saying thank you for the help so far and I have managed to get the new marker locations.

The 2nd part of the question is a JS query really.

I have a link on the main page, under a static map, as below;

```
<a href='adjustmap.php?lat=$retLat&long=$retLong' onClick='return popup(this, \"adjustmap\")'>Click Here to Fine Tune Location</a>
```

The onclick creates the popup window with a bigger map in it with the draggable marker in. I now have the new coordinates in that popup - how do I get them back to the main form?

Phil